# House painting problem where the house row is split and converged back

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a [house painting](https://www.programcreek.com/2014/05/leetcode-paint-house-ii-java/) problem: There are a row of n houses, each house can be painted with one of the k colors. The cost of painting each house with a certain color is different. You have to paint all the houses such that no two adjacent houses have the same color.

The cost of painting each house with a certain color is represented by a n x k cost matrix. For example, costs[0][0] is the cost of painting house 0 with color 0; costs[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdyOQ.png) is the cost of painting house 1 with color 2, and so on... Find the minimum cost to paint all houses.

This can be solved with dynamic programming (see solution in link [house painting](https://www.programcreek.com/2014/05/leetcode-paint-house-ii-java/)). I am trying to solve a very similar problem, but my house row is splitting somewhere in the middle and converging (but sometimes it doesn't), as shown in the picture attached:

[image]

Above you can see the problems that I am facing... Can I solve those problems with dynamic programming ? Is there any other solution for those problems ?

Comment: Can you add the problem definition to your question to make it self contained?

Comment: updated the question...

Answer (score 1):

The problem you described can be solved in polynomial time using dynamic programming whenever the topology of the input houses is a tree (a path is just an even easier special case).

Unless $P=NP$, the problem is not solvable in polynomial time when the input instance is a general graph, since the $k$-coloring problem can be easily reduced to your problem.

However, in your particular case you are in luck since your input instances can always be decomposed in any of the following ways:

- into $2$ paths by deleting two vertices.
- into $2$ trees by deleting one vertex.

You can then guess the the color(s) of the deleted house(s) and update the cost matrix of their neighbors so that if a house $u$ is adjacent to a deleted house $v$ and $v$ is colored with color $c$, the cost of coloring $u$ with $c$ will be $+\infty$ (effectively ensuring that no optimal solution will color $u$ with $c$).

If $k$ is the number of colors, $n$ is the number of houses, and you delete $2$ vertices, solving your problem will take time $O(k^2 \cdot n k) = O(n k^3)$.

If you delete a single house and solve the problem on the resulting tree, you can reduce the time complexity to $O(k \cdot nk) = O(n k^2)$.

---

To solve the problem on trees in time $O(n k)$, root the input tree $T$ in an arbitrary vertex $r$ and let $C(u,c)$ be the cost of coloring vertex $u$ with color $c = \{1, \dots, k\}$.

Define $OPT[u,c]$ as the minimum cost needed to color the subtree of $T$ rooted in $u$ with the additional constraint that vertex $u$ must have a color different from $c$.

Then, if $u$ is a leaf of $T$, you have $OPT[u,c] = \min_{c' \in \{1, \dots, k\} \setminus c} C(u,c')$.
Otherwise, if $u$ is an internal vertex of $T$, let $v_1, \dots, v_h$ be its children. You have $OPT[u, c] = \min_{c' \in \{1, \dots, k\} \setminus c} \left( C(u, c') + \sum_{i=1}^h OPT[v_i, c'] \right)$.

The optimal solution is $\min\{ OPT[r, 1], OPT[r, 2] \}$ (since if $r$ is not colored with color $1$ in an optimal coloring then $OPT[r, 1]$ is exactly the minimum cost to color $T$, while if $r$ is colored with color $1$ then it is not colored with color $2$ and $OPT[r, 2]$ must be the minimum cost needed to color $T$).

A similar argument shows that, for each fixed vertex $u$, all supbroblems $OPT[u, c]$ can be solved in an overall time of $O(k)$ (there are only two interesting values of $c$). The time complexity follows.

Comment: you can't guess the color of the deleted nodes because, in dynamic programming, the total cost of the next nodes depend with the previous nodes (cost[n][c] = min(cost[n-1][!c]). In addition, the main problem is that different minimum can be taken when  calculating the cost of house6, and different minimum can be taken for calculating house5 so the total minimum of the graph was calculated by taken 2 different colors for house4.

Comment: Deleted nodes are... deleted and play no role at all in the dynamic programming. The feasibility of the solution is ensured by changing the costs. From your comment it seems that you want to decompose your instance into paths. As an example, in your first problem you would delete houses 6 and 11. You are left with 2 paths: $P_1$ goes from house 1 to house 9, while $P_2$ goes from house 8 to house 16. You then guess the color $c$ of house 6 and change the cost of paining houses 4 and 8 with $c$ to $+\infty$. You do the same for the color $c'$ of house 11 and change the costs of houses 9 and 13.

Comment: Finally you solve the subproblems corresponding to $P_1$ and $P_2$ separately, using the known dynamic programming algorithm for paths. Since no house in $P_1$ is adjacent to a house in $P_2$, the colors chosen for the houses in $P_1$ will never conflict with the colors chosen for the houses in $P_2$. The only case in which the coloring of $P_1$ (resp. $P_2$) would not be feasible is that in which a neighbor of house 6 is colored with $c$  (resp. a neighbor of house 11 is colored with $c'$). This is impossible because the corresponding costs have been set to $+\infty$.

Comment: but if you guess the color for nodes (houses 6 and 11) than you can not be sure to get the minimum cost... cause maybe, if you choose different colors for those nodes the minimum could have changed ...

Comment: Of course you can... there are only $k^2$ choices of the colors $c$ and $c'$ of houses 6 and 11, respectively. One of these $k^2$ guesses must match the colors of the houses in an optimal solution. Solving the problem for each of the $k^2$ guesses takes time time $O(n \cdot k)$, therefore the total time to solve the problem is $O(nk^3)$.

Comment: In this context guess does not mean "assign arbitrary colors" to the deleted vertices, but rather "try all possible choices of colors" for the deleted vertices.

Comment: So, if I have several T splits and converges than it is K^T options... if T is large than it is not feasible solution....

Comment: But in the problem you described you can decompose each instance in at most two pieces... Keep in mind that the problem is $NP$-hard and hence does not admit a polynomial time solution in general, unless $P=NP$.

Comment: Is the problem is NP-hard for general directed graph with no cycles for sure ?

Comment: Having a directed graph does not help at all because the relation "being painted with a different color" is symmetric anyway. If a directed edge $(u,v)$ means that $u$ must have a different color than $v$, this immediately implies that $v$ must have a different color than $u$. You can then transform any undirected cyclic graph in a directed acyclic graph by suitably assigning directions to the edges (pick any linear order of the vertices and direct edges along this order).

Comment: The problem is NP-hard because it is a generalization of coring. Start from an instance of the 3-coloring problem on a planar graph $G=(V,E)$ ($3$-coloring remains hard on planar graphs), and create an instance on your problem where the graph is $G$, the number of colors is $4$ (it is always possible to color a planar graph with $4$ colors), the cost of painting each house with a color in $\{1,2,3\}$ is $1$, and the cost of painting each house with color $4$ is $2$. There is a $3$-coloring of $G$ if and only if the cost of painting all the houses is $|V|$ (i.e., the color $4$ is never used).